# How to parse two string into one textview

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want my TextView contain 2 String of JSON data.

example.json

```
{
 "volumeInfo": {
   "title": "Computer Architecture",
   "subTitle": "A Quantitative Approach"
}
```

So, from that JSON i want my TextView to be: **Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach**. How should i do? Thanks.

> I only want using one TextView

Comment: String Concatenation is what you're looking for

Comment: Do you want to know how to parse a JSON, concatenate string, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it

```
String title = "Computer Architecture";
String subtitle = "A Quantitative Approach";
TextView.setText(title + ": " + subtitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate Strings and then set it to `TextView` like below:

```
 String title = "Computer Architecture";
 String subtitle = "A Quantitative Approach";
 yourTextView.setText(title + "," + subtitle);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Please check the below code will help you as you want to set the text.

String response = "{" +
        " \"volumeInfo\": {" +
        "   \"title\": \"Computer Architecture\"," +
        "   \"subTitle\": \"A Quantitative Approach\"}" +
        "}";   
 try {
        String title = "", subTitle = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.has("volumeInfo")) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            if (jsonObject1.has("title")) {
                title = jsonObject1.getString("title");
            }
            if (jsonObject1.has("subTitle")) {
                subTitle = jsonObject1.getString("subTitle");
            }
            String combineString = title + ": " + subTitle;
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(combineString);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```